# how to resolve undefined property error

Tags: nodes, debugging

This is my code:

```
function my_module_node_presave($node){
  if ($node->type == 'add_stock') {
    $stock_value = $node->field_stock_value['und'][0]['value'];
    drupal_set_message('stock_value :'.$stock_value);

    $sku = $node->field_sku['und'][0]['value'];
    drupal_set_message('sku :'. $sku);

    $key = $node->field_reference['und'][0]['nid'];
    drupal_set_message('key :'. $key);

    $key1 = node_load($key);
    //$pnode =  $key1->field_product_stock['und'][0]['value'];
    //drupal_set_message('key1 :'.$key1);
    //if (module_exists('uc_stock') && function_exists('uc_stock_adjust')) {

      uc_stock_set($node->$sku, $stock_value);
      uc_stock_adjust($node->$sku, $stock_value);

    //}
  }
}
```

The error I get is the following one:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$tshirt-11 in my_module_node_presave() (line 40 of
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\photo\photogallary\sites\all\modules\my_module\my_module.module).
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$tshirt-11 in my_module_node_presave() (line 41 of
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\photo\photogallary\sites\all\modules\my_module\my_module.module).

Comment: and same error if i use $key in place of $sku in last lines of code

Comment: it should be $node->sku or $node->key without the $

Comment: after removing $ sign the error is
    Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$sku in my_module_node_presave() (line 40 of D:\xampp\htdocs\photo\photogallary\sites\all\modules\my_module\my_module.module).
    Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$sku in my_module_node_presave() (line 41 of D:\xampp\htdocs\photo\photogallary\sites\all\modules\my_module\my_module.module).

Comment: that means there is no variable called sku with in the node object. you could do something like  drupal_set_message"<pre> . print_r($node, true) . "</pre>");

Answer (score 3):

When you write `$node->$sku`, PHP takes the value of `$sku` and uses it as name of a property.
In your case, `$sku` contains `'tshirt-11'`, and `$node->$sku` is equivalent to `$node->tshirt-11`. Since `$node->tshirt-11` is not defined, you get the error you see.

The code you should write is the following one.

```
  uc_stock_set($sku, $stock_value);
  uc_stock_adjust($sku, $stock_value);
```

As side note, the value of a field is accessed using [field_get_items()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/field_get_items/7). The code you use to set `$sku` should be rewritten as the following.

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_sku');
$sku = $items[0];
```

Comment: ok the error is removed. but what im trying to do is not working. I want to increment the stock value of my product node.But that is not changing, it remains the same

Comment: As im using  uc_stock_adjust($sku, $stock_value); to increment my product type node stock value which is referenced to the node on which im currently coding with my_module_node_presave($node)

Comment: That is another question. `:)` The question asks how to fix the error message, which is what this answer says.

Comment: if i do this:$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_sku');
    drupal_set_message('item :'. $item);
 $sku = $items[0];
 drupal_set_message('sku :'. $sku);

Comment: it gives nothing in reply. and one more thing  field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_sku'); is doing what?

Comment: In the first `drupal_set_message()` you use `$item`, not `$items`. As the documentation says, "returns the field items in the language they currently would be displayed."